# Why don't optional parameters work with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, optional-parameters

Why is it that optional parameters with template functions don't work in C++?

(Clarification: I'm hoping to understand *why* C++ was designed such that this wouldn't be possible.)

```
#include <iostream>
template<class T1, class T2> T1 inc(T1 v, T2 u = 1) { return v + u; }
int main() { std::cout << inc(5); }
```

> `prog.cpp:` In function `‘int main()’`: error: no matching function for call to `‘inc(int)’`

Comment: You could make `T2` default to `int` in C++11.

Comment: @chris: Yes but I'm not always using C++11. :\

Comment: So, the question is really why it doesn't work in C++98 ? Considering that you can add an overload `template <typename T1> T1 inc(T1 v) { return v+1; }`, I'd argue that the reason is "not a substantial benefit". C++98 was really late already and such minor things wouldn't warrant another delay.

Answer (score 3):

You got it the wrong way round. Default arguments don't participate in argument deduction:

Argument deduction happens *first*, as part of selecting the desired overload, and *then* the default arguments of that overload are filled in if necessary.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that's what the errors imply... but why? Was this meant to prevent some error? (I'm thinking something along the lines of, if the default value doesn't depend on the template parameter, then it could be deduced as though it were provided...)

Comment: I believe the rules for template deduction and overload resolution are *way* too complicated already, and nobody wanted to add yet another special case here. You can always add another overload that forwards to `inc(v, 1)`.

Comment: It's just the way in which the rules are applied... they're not recursive or iterative. You do overload resolution first, and function call (which comprises filling in defaulted arguments) second. That's how the language is designed. If you have a question *why* the language design is the way it is, you should ask a separate question or edit your question to indicate that.

Comment: @BoPersson: Oh I see... yeah, forwarding works in "nice" cases, but gets annoying for others.

Answer (score 2):

What Kerrek SB said is correct, the compiler just doesn't have enough to deduce T2 from (by what it's allowed to do from the standard).

In this particular case you can probably fix it by using only one template argument for everything, i.e.

```
template< class T > T inc( const T v, const T u = 1 ) { return v + u; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments do not participate in the deduction process (only to overload resolution, and the rules are very difficult to remember -- always keep it simple).

To achieve what you want, you can provide an additional overload:

```
template <class T1, class T2> T1 inc(T1 v, T2 u) { return v + u; }
template <class T> T inc(T v) { return v + T(1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Template functions in C++ are generated at compile time, and are only generated if they are needed.  So you could get a function generated like:

```
inc( int, int );
```

Which would be the T1 = int and T2 = int version.  The compiler can implicitly determine the type if you pass in parameters for every template argument, so:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
inc( a, b );
```

The compiler could generate a function like the one above at compile time, because it can infer that T1 = int and T2 = int.  If however you do what you are doing:

```
inc( 5 );
```

The compiler can determine that T1 = int, but it cannot determine what T2 is.  So no function is generated, and you get the error about the function not existing.  This may be fixable if you use one template parameter:

```
template<class T> T inc(T v, T u = 1) { return v + u; }
```

Or if you provide an overload:

```
template<class T> T inc(T v) { return v + 1; }
```

There is also a third way:

```
inc<int, int>( 5 );
```

But I guess this isn't what you want...